# Elasticsearch not immediately available for search through Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I want to send queries to Elasticsearch through the Elasticsearch plugin within Logstash for every event in process. However, Logstash sends requests to Elasticsearch in bulk and indexed events are not immediately made available for search in Elasticsearch. It seems to me that there will be a lag (up to in process a second or more) between an index passing through Logstash and it being searchable. I don't know how to solve this.

Do you have any idea ?

Thank you for your time.

Joe

Comment: Sounds a lot like this issue https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-elasticsearch/issues/151 which hasn't had much traction yet.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to configure logstash to only treat one event at a time (filter  + store in elasticsearch) before treating the next one ?

Comment: Yes, you can use the `http` output instead of the `elasticsearch` one. The "advantage" is that you can specify the `refresh=true` parameter and be sure that in the next event the document will be available when searched via the `elasticsearch` filter plugin.

Comment: Note, however, that this will be tremendously slow since you'll refresh your ES cluster on every index operation... if you expect a high write load, that can dramatically lower the performance of your cluster. A better approach would be to use the `aggregate` filter and only index the data once it's deemed "complete".